# Frictional effects in pilot-static probes

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity

For pilot static probes frictional effects are neglected for high velocity measurement, so that bernoulli equation can be applicable.

But isn't head loss proportional to square of average velocity, which implies that frictional effects are significant and should not be neglected at high flow velocities .

[image: cengel and cimbala]

Please point out what I'm missing here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first paragraph which is proposition that I'm having a doubt with is from the section on pilot static probes in fluid mechanics by cengel and cimbala.. the second paragraph is from the same book.. other than that I think I have made myself pretty clear.